# Jira dont work with mailgun.org

Tags: smtp, jira, mailgun

I have an issue with `Mailgun.org` in combination with our selfhosted `Jira.`

I want to add it as SMTP Outgoing, but he said `Username/Password Error`. Yeah , I triple checked the Username/Password combination.

In Confluence, Bamboo, Stash work the same Configuration fine.

The `atlassian-jira.log` just said:

```
2014-01-24 11:49:32,219 http-bio-8080-exec-22 ERROR xx 709x65334x1 hub9zg xx,127.0.0.1 /secure/admin/VerifySmtpServerConnection!update.jspa [plugins.mail.webwork.VerifyMailServer] Unable to authenticate to smtp.mailgun.org
```

Without TLS, the same.

If I try a Gmail Account, its works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could try enabling debugging on outgoing mail in Logging & Profiling and checking the log again.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and spoke to Jira support. It turns out the 'Test Connection' button was returning that it had failed with `Unable to authenticate to smtp.mailgun.org` message.

However if you actually add the Mailgun details as a smtp server it works correctly.
You can verify by sending a test email afterwards.

They have added a bug report for this issue.
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-41342

Comment: Two years later, this is still an issue.  I just wanted to add that the test email didn't even work for me.  JIRA kept telling giving me Timeout and Username/Password related errors when I clicked 'Test Connect' or 'Send Test Email'.  Anyway, I was in the middle of troubleshooting when I started receiving emails about tasks being created by my PM.  So despite JIRA telling me it doesn't work.  It actually does.  So if you are having issue, put the credentials in and save, then try triggering an actual notification to test.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me. Very confusing since I receive an error message if I set it up any other way.

Protocol: SMTP (do not use secure smtp option)

Host Name: smtp.mailgun.org

SMTP Port: 587

Timeout: 10000

TLS: Enabled (checked)

Username/Password: Your mailgun postmaster username and password

Comment: FWIW, this is the only solution that seems to have worked for me in 2020.